# Display Error Message in a separate div using jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation and I am wanting to display the error message in a div `<div class="alert alert-error" id="errorContainer">` The default of showing below the forms does not work with my form design.

The validation script is linked to the page I have the form on and it looks like:

```
    $(function validate() {

    var rules = {
                rules: {
                    full_name: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        maxlength: 50,
                        required: true
                    },
                    address: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        required: true
                    },
                    city: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    state: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        maxlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    zip: {
                        minlength:5, 
                        maxlength:5,
                        required: true
                    },
                    phone: {
                        required: true,
                        phoneUS: true
                    },
                    phone_other: {
                        required: true,
                        phoneUS: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    date_to_start: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    ssn: {
                        required: true,
                        ssn: true,
                    },
                    salary: {
                        required: true
                    }

                }
            };

        var validationObj = $.extend (rules, Application.validationRules);

        $('#employment-application').validate(validationObj);

});
```

Now I did try changing `$('#employment-application').validate(validationObj);` to the code below as well as tried adding it to the bottom of the page I have the form on, both gave negative results. The script seems to add `style="display:none;"` to the `errorContainer` and does not load any errors anywhere.

(tried changing `$('#employment-application').validate(validationObj);` to the below)

```
$("#employment-application").validate({
        errorContainer: "#errorContainer", 
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorContainer", 
        errorElement: "li"
    })
```

So re-cap, I am wanting to use jQuery Form Validation and display the error messages received in a separate div because the default does not work with my form design.

Comment: You have the `.validate()` _method_ inside of a function named `validate()`.  Then what calls the function?  Typically, the `.validate()` method simply goes inside of a DOM ready event handler.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `errorPlacement` option to pass a callback like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cMhQ7/

I've used a standard of the `div` id being the input element's name concatenated with a `_validate` suffix but you can change as you wish.

HTML

```
<form id="employment-application" method="post">
    <input name="full_name" type="text" />
    <div id="full_name_validate"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(function validate() {

    var rules = {
        rules: {
            full_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 50,
                required: true
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var name = $(element).attr("name");
            error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
        },
    };

    $('#employment-application').validate(rules);

});
```

Comment: Well this doesn't hide the div anymore so we must be getting closer. It doesn't however display the errors. Is it because it's in a linked file?

Comment: Yes your JSFiddle is working. but once I put it into my script it does nothing. Here take a look: http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/employment/js/demo/validation.js

Comment: Ok so, I copied your entire script and replaced it with mine. Must have had something unforeseen on my script that was preventing this from working. Haven't tried it with multiple input's yet. I'll approve answer once I have.

Comment: Ok everything is working just the way I was wanting it to. Thank you so much:)

Comment: is there any way that we can put all msg in 1 div ? `error.appendTo($("#div_msgsvalidate"));` will add msg each time i Click submit.

Comment: To hide the div, please place error container within the form

Comment: Why is the `.validate()` method inside of a function called `validate()`?  The `.validate()` method is only used to initialize the plugin and subsequent calls are ignored... so it does not make any sense to have it within a function that potentially gets called more than once.

Comment: @Sparky why would it get called more than once? The function will only run once the DOM is ready. Which should only ever be once for a page. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-callback

Comment: The `validate` function could have also been an anonymous function, but I like to always name my functions, so they show up in stack traces and profiling etc.

Answer (score 5):

If only want to change the default placement to certain elements, you can use this improvement.
This implements the default behaviour of validate script

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        var name    = $(element).attr("name");
        var $obj    = $("#" + name + "_validate");
        if($obj.length){
            error.appendTo($obj);
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
```