# how jquery validator can custom divs for both error and success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've been looking for a day now trying to figure out how I can get real time error messages to appear, each in a different div.

I am using custom icons and divs for each input field and for each error, as well as success icons for each input field too. However, the code I have been trying strangely changes when other input field are clicked.

here is the JS :

```
$(function validate() {
var  invalidFirstName = $("#blankField"),
    validFirstName = $('#validCheck');
  var  rules = {
    rules: {
       user_first_name: {
            required: true
        }

    errorPlacement: function (error,element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "user_first_name"){
            (invalidFirstName).removeClass('hidden');
            (validFirstName).addClass('hidden');

        }
    },

    success: function() {
      //  if (element.attr("name") == "user_first_name"){
            (invalidFirstName).addClass('hidden');
            (validFirstName).removeClass('hidden');
       // }
    }
};

$('#briefStepOne').validate(rules);

});
```

As you can see I tried to do an if statement too, but then it doesn't work at all! Any help would be great.

here is the layout of my html :

```
 <div class="form-fields input-text">
        <div class="input-interaction-container">
            <label for="user_first_name" class="user_first_name">First Name&#42;</label>


            <input type="text" name="user_first_name" id="user_first_name" maxlength="50" class="user_first_name">
        </div>


        <div class="form-error-section pure-hidden-phone hidden" id = "blankField">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
            <p>Field cannot be left blank</p>
        </div>
        <div class=" hidden form-error-section valid-icon pure-hidden-phone" id="validCheck">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-fields input-text">
        <div class="input-interaction-container">
            <label for="user_last_name">Last Name&#42;</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_last_name" id="user_last_name" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class=" hidden form-error-section pure-hidden-phone">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
            <p>Field cannot be left blank</p>
        </div>
        <div class=" hidden form-error-section valid-icon pure-hidden-phone">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATED JS FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#briefStepOne'.validate({

        rules: {

            user_first_name: {
                required: true
            },
            user_last_name:{
                required:true
            },
            user_email_address:{
                required:true
            }
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error,element) {

            if (element.attr('name') == 'user_first_name'){

                $('#blankField').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#validCheck').addClass('hidden');
            } else if (element.attr('name') == 'user_last_name'){

                $('#last-name-empty').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#last-name-good').addClass('hidden');

            }

        },

        success: function(label) {

            if (label.attr('id') == 'user_first_name-error'){

                $('#blankField').addClass('hidden');
                $('#validCheck').removeClass('hidden');

            } else if (label.attr('id') == 'user_last_name-error'){
                $('#last-name-empty').addClass('hidden');
                $('#last-name-good').removeClass('hidden');

            }
        }


    }));
    });
```

Comment: You have a function called `validate()` and the plugin's method is called `.validate()`.  `$('#briefStepOne').validate(rules)` is the method contained within a function with the same name.  How is that going to do anything?  It's never going to get called.

Comment: I will have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725414/call-jquery-validate-plugin-without-submitting-the-form

Comment: also looking at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zMYVq/

it doesn't seem to react to the first field as well as it does to the second field. the error message does not show

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMYVq/) is working exactly as it should and all/both messages are appearing.  Explain more.

Comment: Syntax error here:  `$('#briefStepOne'.validate({` and here:  `}));`  Notice the missing and extra parentheses.

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding how it should work, but without pressing any buttons and just adding text then removing it only the second text box shows the "This field is required. " message, the first text box doesn't seem to show it, it shows it only after one of the buttons has been clicked.

Comment: in your fiddle which part of it calls the main function ? 
because at the moment i have the updates js code as shown above and it does nothing, where shall i call it, sorry im really confused now

Comment: i was looking at this example when doing my code :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021615/display-error-message-in-a-separate-div-using-jquery-validation

Comment: You've simply picked [a terrible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021615/display-error-message-in-a-separate-div-using-jquery-validation) to follow, as there is no explanation about what is calling the function in the first place.

Comment: The `.validate()` ***method*** gets called ONCE within a DOM ready event handler.  The plugin then _automatically_ captures the various triggering events.  You **do not call** anything else.

Comment: so would you say the above updated js file should be working or not?

Comment: This is how your code should look/work:  http://jsfiddle.net/93sjn1dn/  <- This is constructed and working as it should.  [If you want to modify it, then properly apply the appropriate options from the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org//validate).  I have to leave for a while.  Good luck.  A modified version:  http://jsfiddle.net/93sjn1dn/1/

Comment: i think theres a miss understnading of what i think the plugin can do. I wanted it to display the fa-fa icons when there is an error and when their is a success yet it does not show them. that is why i was toggling between the hidden classes. yes these are not in the fiddle example above. can the plugin do what I explained?

Comment: Yes you can with a little more work.  I just wanted to provide you with a much better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been looking for a day now trying to figure out how I can get
>   real time error messages to appear, each in a different div.

That's why you have the jQuery Validate plugin.  It does this automatically.  In other words, you're trying to toggle hard-coded `div` elements when the plugin is trying to create and toggle its own elements.

There are quite a few syntax errors...

1. Missing a closing brace and comma after `rules`...

   ```
   ....
   rules: {
       user_first_name: {
           required: true
       }
   }, // <- this is missing
   errorPlacement: ....
   ```
2. If you declare `invalidFirstName = $("#blankField")`, then you would not need to put `invalidFirstName` inside of parentheses...

   ```
   (invalidFirstName).removeClass('hidden');
   ```

   should be...

   ```
   invalidFirstName.removeClass('hidden');
   ```

   This is a moot point anyway, as per #4 below.
3. I cannot see how you're calling your `$(function validate() {...` which encloses your `.validate()` method.  However, this is not how to use this plugin.   The `.validate()` method should only be called once to *initialize* the plugin on your form, as any subsequent calls are always ignored.  In other words, `.validate()` goes inside of the DOM ready event handler function, not inside of any other function or event handler.  Once initialized, validation is triggered *automatically* by certain events that are captured *automatically*.
4. Then you would leverage [the plugin's multitude of options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) to insert the dynamic error message into a `div`.  The plugin then *automatically* toggles the visibility of these error messages.  You would never need to hard-code any error message containers in HTML or write a function that toggles a `hidden` class.
5. Not sure if you simply left them out of your OP or if you really never used them, however, your input elements must be inside a `<form></form>` container.  This plugin will not work otherwise.

---

- Refer to [the SO Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for a simple demo and links to more information.
- Also browse the working examples in some of [the nearly 5000 SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) about this plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the vey detailed answer! 
point 1 and 2 I have fixed and updated my code as you can see. 

when / how would the plugin have to be called, for clarification purposes  -  i thought it was being called using $('#briefStepOne').validate(rules);

also when an error occurs I want an icon to appear as well as my personalised text. how can I edit the plugin div for it to contain an icon and style it the way I want to? I have a strict design that I need to follow.

Comment: @ElinaLulle, Even if the `.validate()` _method_ was the same thing as your `validate()` _function_ (which it's not), how could that work when `$('#briefStepOne').validate(rules)` is contained INSIDE of your custom `validate()` function?